# Mapping c++ to assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, clang

When compiling some code with clang 3.9.1 and optimizations (-O2) I ran into some unexpected behavior at run time that I have not seen with other compilers (clang 3.8 and gcc 6.3).

I thought I may have some unintentional undefined behavior (compiling with ubsan removes the unexpected behavior) so I tried to simplify the program and found that one particular function seems to be causing the differences in behavior.

Now, I am mapping the assembly back to  c++ to see where it's going wrong to try and determine why this is occurring and there are a few portions I am having difficulty mapping back.

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/g/ccrV7m)

C++:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

enum class FooState { A, B };

struct Foo {
  std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter{0};
  std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter_a{0};
  std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter_b{0};
};

//__attribute__((noinline))
FooState to_state(const std::int64_t c) {
  return c >= 0 ? FooState::A : FooState::B;
}

static const int NUM_MODIFIES = 100;

int value_a = 0, value_b = 0;
Foo foo;
std::atomic<std::int64_t> total_sum{0};

void test_function() {
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    const std::int64_t count =
        foo.counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    const FooState state = to_state(count);

    int &val = FooState::A == state ? value_a : value_b;
    if (val == NUM_MODIFIES) {
      total_sum += val;
      done = true;
    }

    std::atomic<std::int64_t> &c =
        FooState::A == state ? foo.counter_a : foo.counter_b;
    c.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  }
}
```

Assembly:

```
test_function():                     # @test_function()
        test    rax, rax
        setns   al
        lock
        inc     qword ptr [rip + foo]
        mov     ecx, value_a
        mov     edx, value_b
        cmovg   rdx, rcx
        cmp     dword ptr [rdx], 100
        je      .LBB1_3
        mov     ecx, foo+8
        mov     edx, value_a
.LBB1_2:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        test    al, 1
        mov     eax, foo+16
        cmovne  rax, rcx
        lock
        inc     qword ptr [rax]
        test    rax, rax
        setns   al
        lock
        inc     qword ptr [rip + foo]
        mov     esi, value_b
        cmovg   rsi, rdx
        cmp     dword ptr [rsi], 100
        jne     .LBB1_2
.LBB1_3:
        lock
        add     qword ptr [rip + total_sum], 100
        test    al, al
        mov     eax, foo+8
        mov     ecx, foo+16
        cmovne  rcx, rax
        lock
        inc     qword ptr [rcx]
        ret
```

I have found that marking `to_state` as `noinline` or changing `done` to be global seems to "fix" the unexpected behavior.

The unexpected behavior I am seeing is that when counter is >= 0 then counter_a should be incremented otherwise counter_b should be incremented.  From what I can tell sometimes this is not happening, but determining exactly when/why has been difficult.

One part of the assembly I could use some help with are the `test rax, rax; setns al` and the `test al, 1` portions.  It seems like the initial test would not set `al` deterministically and then that value is used to determine which counter to increment, but perhaps I am misunderstanding something.

Below is a smallish example to demonstrate this issue.  It usually hangs forever when compiled with clang 3.9 and -O2 and runs to completion otherwise.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <thread>
#include <cstdio>

enum class FooState { A, B };

struct Foo {
  std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter{0};
  std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter_a{0};
  std::atomic<std::int64_t> counter_b{0};
};

//__attribute__((noinline))
FooState to_state(const std::int64_t c) {
  return c >= 0 ? FooState::A : FooState::B;
}

//__attribute__((noinline))
FooState to_state2(const std::int64_t c) {
  return c >= 0 ? FooState::A : FooState::B;
}

static const int NUM_MODIFIES = 100;

int value_a = 0, value_b = 0;
Foo foo;
std::atomic<std::int64_t> total_sum{0};

void test_function() {
  bool done = false;
  while (!done) {
    const std::int64_t count =
        foo.counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    const FooState state = to_state(count);

    int &val = FooState::A == state ? value_a : value_b;
    if (val == NUM_MODIFIES) {
      total_sum += val;
      done = true;
    }

    std::atomic<std::int64_t> &c =
        FooState::A == state ? foo.counter_a : foo.counter_b;
    c.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
  }
}

int main() {
  std::thread thread = std::thread(test_function);

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i <= NUM_MODIFIES; ++i) {
    const std::int64_t count =
        foo.counter.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst);
    const FooState state = to_state2(count);

    unsigned log_count = 0;

    auto &inactive_val = FooState::A == state ? value_b : value_a;
    inactive_val = i;

    if (FooState::A == state) {
      foo.counter_b.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      const auto accesses_to_wait_for =
          foo.counter.exchange((std::numeric_limits<std::int64_t>::min)(),
                               std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      while (accesses_to_wait_for !=
             foo.counter_a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();

        if(++log_count <= 10) {
          std::printf("#1 wait_for=%ld, val=%ld\n", accesses_to_wait_for, 
            foo.counter_a.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));
        }
      }
    } else {
      foo.counter_a.store(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);

      auto temp = foo.counter.exchange(0, std::memory_order_seq_cst);
      std::int64_t accesses_to_wait_for = 0;
      while (temp != INT64_MIN) {
        ++accesses_to_wait_for;
        --temp;
      }

      while (accesses_to_wait_for !=
             foo.counter_b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        std::this_thread::yield();

        if (++log_count <= 10) {
          std::printf("#2 wait_for=%ld, val=%ld\n", accesses_to_wait_for, 
            foo.counter_b.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst));
        }
      }
    }

    std::printf("modify #%lu complete\n", i);
  }

  std::printf("modifies complete\n");

  thread.join();

  const std::size_t expected_result = NUM_MODIFIES;
  std::printf("%s\n", total_sum == expected_result ? "ok" : "fail");
}
```

Comment: Why are you looking at assembly language to debug code? Create mvce and use a debugger?

Comment: You keep saying *"unexpected behavior"* but I'm still unsure which behavior you aren't expecting? Could you please clarify?

Comment: @UnholySheep Sorry about that.  I have updated the post with more information.

Comment: the whole value_a, value_b thing that really does nothing at all is strange.  Set to 0 and compared against, but not used.  Anytime I see globals and threads, I get nervous.

Comment: I'm not very skilled with 64b ABIs, but the `test rax,rax` at the beginning is puzzling me, can't figure it out. The `rax` is supposed to be scratch register, so it's not defined whether `al` will be 0 or 1 after that `setns al`? That will later affect `counter_a` or `counter_b` is used in first iteration of loop, so it's not "harmless" UB IMHO. But maybe I'm just overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Also pretty sure that all your compares with atomics are not thread safe.  Yes, they use atomics, but the ? operator still will occur across multiple instructions and therefore it's values can change.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Would you mind mentioning the line(s) you are talking about?  I'm missing where the compares you mention are occurring.

Comment: Did the complicated logic of `test_function` emerged after cutting out original code to provide minimal example? Because as it is now, it can be probably written in quite simpler way on C++ level, but I'm not even going to try to rewrite it, if the full version requires it this weird way. (edit: removed, didn't check properly source)

Comment: @Ped7g Thanks for pointing out the complication.  It emerged when trying to get smaller test case (a straight reduction of the original actually doesn't exhibit this behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure (didn't debug it, just simulation in head), but I think the both pairs `test rax,rax` + `setns al` are testing something wrong.

Result of first depends on whether `rax < 0` upon calling the function (UB), and the other test inside loop will be always "NS" (testing 32b address in `rax` => SF=0 => `al`=1), so fixed `al` == 1 for the remaining loops will always select the `counter_a`.

Now I read your question, and you have the same suspicion (I did take a look at code only first).

Comment: Yes, that was the part I was suspicious about as well.  Do you see anywhere in the code that might allow for this to be generated?

Comment: @CTT not really. If it would be `state` itself, I would expect the opposite logic (enum being A=0, B=1, while `al` is setns to 1/0 instead). I did think it may be part "after receiving return value of `to_state()`, before removing it due to inline", but the inverse logic doesn't support this. So it's probably lot more complicated. I'm still not even 100% sure I deciphered it correctly. Also I don't see anything UB-like in C++ sources, but I'm not C++ guru. One thing to check whether the aliasing through reference is valid, but AFAIG (g=guess), it is. (So I think you hit compiler bug.. 50%?)

Comment: This did turn out to be a compiler bug.  The fix is here: https://reviews.llvm.org/rL291630